# Qual a melhor estrategia para criar um registro e associar a outro por meio de uma tabela pivot?

Tags: laravel

O trecho abaixo pega os dados de sessão do usuário, utiliza o método `posts` presente na model `User` para criar um novo post no banco.

Posteriormente recupero o `id` do registro criado e associo este registro a uma categoria por meio da tabela `pivot`:

```
if(\Auth::user() && $dbId = \Auth::user()->posts()
                                         ->create($request->except(['categoria']))) {

            $post = Post::find($dbId->id);
            $post->categorias()->attach($request->input('categoria'));

            return redirect('/painel/post')
                    ->with(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Post criado com sucesso!']);
}
```

Mas estou com dúvida se está seria a melhor solução?

***O código desta model está disponível em:*** [*PostController*](https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/larablog-beta/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Painel/PostController.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria assim, seria a forma lógica aproveitar a instância criada pelo método `create`:

```
if(\Auth::user()) 
{
    $post = \Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->except(['categoria']))
    $post->categorias()->attach($request->input('categoria'));

    return redirect('/painel/post')
               ->with(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Post criado com sucesso!']);
}
```